# android.intent.action.SEND on Android O - URI contains file:// urls instead of content://

Tags: android, android-intent, send, mediastore, android-8.0-oreo

My app registers action send in manifest, this way:

```
<intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Then, to get images uris, code:

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();

        switch(action)
        {
            case Intent.ACTION_SEND:
                uris.add(getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM));
                break;


            case Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE:
                uris = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                break;
        }
```

I'm experiencing different behaviour on Android O. On pre O Android versions (4.4 to 7.1 tested), I'm getting URI in format `content://`, so I have used this method (found on stackoverflow btw) to decode uris and convert them to direct image path:

```
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri)
    {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try
        {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cursor != null)
            {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

As mentioned above, all is fine on Android 4.4 - 7.1. On Android 8, intent contains already decoded image uris, in `file://` format, and method `getRealPathFromUri` throws an exception.

I can't find anything related to that change in Android 8 when searching Google documentation. Any idea how to get the same uri format on Android O?

Not sure if it matters, activity receiving action send intent is defined this way:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
            <intent-filter>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use getRealPathFromUri if you have a file:// uri. Well you should never use getRealPathFromUri. Bad practice.

Comment: What is good practice then? I must use `getRealPathFromUri` in case when I have `content://` uri. There is always `content://` uri, except Android 8 - on Android 8 it's always `file://`. I would like to get consistent solution - always `content://` or always `file://` on all Android versions. It seem the have changed something on android 8

Comment: Good practice is to support both and never try to convert a content uri to a file path. There is no need for such a conversion either. Please tell why you would need it.

Comment: I need direct file path, `content://` is useless for me.

Comment: Please tell why.

Comment: Scenario: open system gallery, select image, share it to my app. My app receives image uri. Then I need to upload image to my server. I need direct image path to do so.

Comment: It is hard to believe that Android 8 would convert a content scheme to a file scheme.  Which app is sending the uris? And how?

Comment: No. To upload that image to a server you can use the content scheme of course. Instead of opening a FileInputStream on a file path you can open an InputStream on the content scheme. All rest of the code is the same.

Comment: I need to resize image first, I used `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` to do that. It expects direct file path provided as String.

Comment: Use BitmapFactory.decodeFromStream instead.

Comment: Do you mean `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`? I need to pass `InputStream`, not uri

Comment: Yes. decodeStream. And indeed pass it the InputStream i told you to open on the uri.

Comment: InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

Comment: Can you clarify? I have Uri: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html object. decodeStream needs InputStream

Comment: Well, it's not Android 8 issue. It's an app that I used to share picture (3rd party Gallery app).

Comment: Anyhow i showed you how to open an input stream on the uri. Then you can use the input stream in decodeStream. What do you need more?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Your idea is better

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer. Difference is because of app used to share picture: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplemobiletools.gallery

My solution (I feel it's not the best):

```
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri)
    {
        String path = contentUri.toString();
        if(path.contains("file://"))
        {
            path = contentUri.getPath();
            return path;
        }

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try
        {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cursor != null)
            {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a nonsense solution. Of course you would just remove file:// from a path if it started with that. But your app is wrong trying to convert a content scheme to a file path.

Comment: Well, now I need to figure out how to pass uri to Intent as extra, now I'm working with String file paths, which is simple. You are right I don't need to convert content scheme to file path in my case, but I can imagine sometimes it's needed (for example, to display image location for app user).

Comment: If my app shares an image located in its private internal memory then your app cannot decode a real path from the received content scheme. Your approach only works because you use some Gallery app that uses the MediaStore.  Sooner or later you will find out your self. Stop trying to get a real path.

Comment: Try to write a file FileProvider app and then share a picture. You will see that your first app cannot decode a real path.

Comment: I wonder how an app on Android 8 can send a file:// scheme. As that is already forbidden in Android 7. The app would get a FileUriExposedException.

Comment: Are pictures from private internal memory visible in system gallery?

Comment: No. They are not in the MediaStore. And hence not in the Gallery. Thats one reason why your real path wishes are bad.

Comment: I actually need to support only images accesible via system gallery. I doubt there is any other scenario possible. End user will share images from Gallery, no any other way

Comment: It will bite you sooner or later if you do not adhere to the content scheme completely. The file scheme will disappear.

Comment: Yep, you are probably right. Thanks for explanation

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeStream needs RECT parameter, which is unknown. If I pass null there bitmap is not created. But I think I need to create separate question for that

Comment: You dont need to ask. Code has been published so many times on this site. It seems as if you never read this site or fail to search. No. It does not need a RECT parameter. It needs an options parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> Use FileUtils.java file

---

---

[FileUtils.java](https://gist.github.com/HBiSoft/15899990b8cd0723c3a894c1636550a8)

---

---

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
File uploadFile = new File(FileUtils.getRealPath(activity.this,  data.getData()));
}
```

---

---